# Angular - [].concat.apply return empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have this Ionic code:

```
.factory('resultsFactory', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) { 
  var results = {};  

  function _all(){
    var d = $q.defer();
    var palabras =  $rootScope.textAreaOfrecer.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    var solicitudes = [];
    Promise.all(
              solicitudes = palabras.map(palabra => $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("solCompras").orderByChild("palabras/" 
                                               + palabra).equalTo(true) ) )
                     );

    var array = [].concat.apply([],solicitudes);

    d.resolve(array);

    return d.promise;       
  }

  results.all = _all;
  return results;
})
```

The problem is that the code: var array = [].concat.apply([],solicitudes); return an empty array.

[image: json of solicitudes]

Comment: Hi. What output are you expecting? Please post more details so that we can assist you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[].concat.apply(solicitudes)` instead. It may be that `palabras` is an empty array, then `[].map(...) == []` can return `Promise.all(solicitudes)` directly.

```
function _all() {
        var palabras = $rootScope.textAreaOfrecer.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        return Promise.all(palabras.map((palabra) => {
            return $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("solCompras").orderByChild("palabras/" + palabra).equalTo(true));
        }));
    }
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: check the collection `palabras` whether is an empty array? if true then palabras.map(...) always return []

Comment: debug map/concat function whether always return []?

Comment: in fact this is not the problem. "array = [].concat.apply([],solicitudes);"   array is what always keep in null. but "solicitudes" have elements. its an array of arrays that i want to unify

Comment: the code "array = [].concat.apply([],solicitudes);"  no problem.if `solicitudes` have elements & array is null then the `[].concat.apply([],solicitudes)`  concat/apply function may be changed by someone.you can use `var  strings=[].concat.apply([],['foo','bar']);console.log(strings);`before `array` assignment and see the result.

Comment: In fact,you can use [].concat([]) directly because `palabras` is an array,using   concat.apply is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.solicitudes = [{post: 'Loading..'}];


Promise.all(
      $scope.solicitudes = palabras.map(palabra => $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("solCompras").orderByChild("palabras/" + palabra
                                                   ).equalTo(true) ) )
             ).then( function (){
                               //http://www.jstips.co/en/flattening-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/
                               var myNewArray = $scope.solicitudes.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                                 return prev.concat(curr);
                               });

                               $scope.solicitudes = myNewArray;
                         });
```